# AWS Amplify does not give me the correct data

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I got this strange error, which I did not have since the last time I updated Amplify. I have auto generated GraphQL mutations that create an entry in the database. I also have a function that lists the data in the database.

So when I save a new entry (I can see it saved in the database) and try to fetch it by the list method. It will sometimes make me save the SAME data multiple times untill it fetches and sometimes it fetches instantly. I have not changed my code since the last patch and this strange behavior started recently.

I thought it had with the limit to do so I cleared all the old data + increased limit on read. but the issue still stays

```
 await API.graphql({ query: mutations.createBooking, variables: { input: data } })

This it the create method
```

```
      const serviceData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listBookings, {
        filter: {
          date: {
            eq: selectedDate
          }
        },
        limit: 999999999
      }))

This is the List method.
```

---

Additional code after edit

```
  async function saveData() {
    setIsSending(true);
    try {
      await API.graphql({ query: mutations.createBooking, variables: { input: data } })
        .then(async i => {

          const getService = services.filter(i => i.id === data.service)[0];
          let temp = {
            ...data,
            date: `${stringDate.dayname} ${stringDate.dd} ${stringDate.mm} ${stringDate.yyyy}`,
            service: getService.name,
            address: data.shouldPickup ? data.address : "Adress"
          }

          await emailjs.send(
            process.env.REACT_APP_ENV_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID,
            process.env.REACT_APP_ENV_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID,
            temp,
            process.env.REACT_APP_ENV_EMAILJS_PUB_KEY)
            .then((result) => {
              setIsSending(false);
            }, (error) => {
              console.log(error.text);
            });
          runSuccesAlert()
          handleClose();
        })
        .catch(i => {
          setAlertMsg({
            severity: "error",
            msg: "Något gick fel i systemet, prova ringa/maila medan vi fixar det.",
          })
          console.log("Err", JSON.stringify(i))
        })
    } catch (err) { console.log('error fetching services', err) }
  }
```

---

```
  async function getAllDates() {
    try {
      const serviceData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listBookings, {
        filter: {
          date: {
            eq: selectedDate
          }
        },
        limit: 999999999
      }))
      const s = serviceData.data.listBookings.items;

      let dates = [];

      if (s.length !== 0) {
        dates = s.filter(i => !i._deleted).map(t => t.time);
      }

      const d = dateName(selectedDate, dates);

      setAvailableTimes(d.availableTime);
      setData(prevState => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          time: d.availableTime[0] || null
        }
      });
      setStringDate(d);
      setData(prevState => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          date: selectedDate
        }
      });
    } catch (err) { console.log('error fetching services', err) }
  }
```

I also tried console.log the await

```
{
    "createBooking": {
        "id": "4020a839-b951-4288-9663-06c59d69a263",
        "service": "51516cf1-e490-433e-989d-adfa829ea345",
        "date": "2023-03-09T14:05:49.748Z",
        "email": "boka@boka.com",
        "phone": "070000",
        "address": "",
        "approvedTerms": true,
        "name": "bokaupp",
        "time": "19:00",
        "shouldPickup": false,
        "createdAt": "2023-03-09T14:06:27.090Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-03-09T14:06:27.090Z",
        "_version": 1,
        "_deleted": null,
        "_lastChangedAt": 1678370787109
    }
}
```

I can see it saved in DB but it wont show when I list it

Comment: What is the error message? Have you tried this via the AppSync console? `limit` is optional FYI.

Comment: @Luke I get no errors or anything.

Comment: Can you run try `{await API.graphql({ query: mutations.createBooking, variables: { input: data } })} catch (err) {console.error("Error Message: ", err) };`? Maybe then you can see the error message, as there should be one. Otherwise assign your `await` to a variable and then `console.log()` that variable.

Comment: @Luke Yeah sorry. I should have appended the entire code block, I do have a catch for the error but as it's not really an error it doesn't catch the error. I can't for the life of me figure out why it acts like this

Comment: Please could you add as much code as possible? Also, did you try run this query in AppSync?

Comment: I added more code and I tried via AppSync. I get the same result as I get in the frontend. @Luke

Comment: Without the filter and limit, does the query work?

Comment: Yes it works, but its very glitchy. Some days it just works like a charm and other times it just does not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252415/discussion-between-luke-and-saman93).

Answer (score 0):

Dynamodb is eventually consistent. You can change the settings but it impacts performance.An alternative is to have a loading transition state where you wait a few hundred ms before calling the list/search queries. Receiving the expected list of data and will take it out of loading transition/animation.